# Diferencia entre ' y ` y en qué lenguajes se utiliza y porqué?

Tags: javascript

Hoy estaba revisando un código y me he encontrado esta sentencia, que hasta ahora nunca la había visto (tampoco es que sea un experto).

```js
const  task = {
  id : 10
 }
 console.log(`task id = ${task.id}`)
```

Al principio pensé que se trataba de una comilla simple " ' ", pero claro, no tenía mucho sentido, pues quiero representar el valor contenido en la variable, por lo que la gracia está en usar esa comilla, que desconozco si tiene algún nombre.

Mis preguntas son...

Cómo se denomina la ` en inglés y castellano?
En qué lenguajes se utiliza? Yo solo lo he visto en javascript, de momento.

Entiendo que la ventaja es evitarte algo como esto que sería un poco más largo

```js
const task = {
id : 10
}
console.log('task id = ') + task.id;
```

pero agradecería que comentárais si hay alguna ventaja adicional que se me esté pasando.

Comment: Se llama backtick a la comilla invertida. Son plantillas de cadenas de texto o template literals. Buscando en google puedes obtener tooda la informacion al respecto que desees. Un saludo

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia, sobre todo por la parte de *¿En qué lenguajes se utiliza?*. Tu ejemplo es JS

Comment: se conoce en español como [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) y el segundo es un error

Comment: otra ventaja es poder escribir múltiples lineas sin la necesidad de agregar un `+` y un salto de línea o el texto `\n`

Comment: el signo en si es un *acento grave*